# How can I get the PKId of first and last record of each day while iterating through 300M + records and insert that info into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

**Yes, I know: Disclaimer** Once you see the problem and the question, you'll realize that SQL Server is definitely not the best solution for this, but unfortunately, this is what we have right now. I'm slowly trying to move to NoSQL for logging table, but it'll take time.

**Setup**: SQL Server 2014.

**Context** I have a table that stores approximately 2-2.5 million records/day and just given its sheer functionality, only its PK (auto-incremented) is indexed. This makes it extremely hard and slow for us to run any type of queries where we can incorporate other columns in WHERE clauses.

**Table**

Name: LogTable

Columns:

ID (int, PK, Clustered index)

StoredDate (datetime)

Few other columns containing information that can be used in WHERE clauses

**Leverage the indexed PK** I can speed up the search by adding the PKid in the WHERE clause and set a limit, similar to:

> SELECT someColumns FROM LogTable WHERE LogTableID >1000000 AND LogTableId <2000000 AND otherWHereClauseItems

**Goal** The goal is to have a separate table that stores the id of first and last record of each day, so once the user is running some queries using a UI, I can inject the additional WHERE clause item to get the results that are within that first and last ID range. Once I've run the initial seed process (capture all the IDs from past records), I can then schedule a nightly job that'll now continue to add a row for each day.

**Struggle** The table has over 500 million records and I just can't seem to find a good way to iterate through all the records, and then find the first and last of the day, especially when the date column is not indexed.

**Question** Can you guys please recommend something that might help me with this problem? If you could just point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: self join to find the max record per day? More or less like `... table as alias1 LEFT JOIN table as alias2 ON alias1.StoredDate  < alias2.StoredDate  WHERE alias2.StoredDate  IS NULL` ?  Edit: Well this one really needs that index on StoredDate otherwise it will not scale..

Comment: Thank you, and yes you're correct, this would need an index on the date and that's something we cannot afford to add unfortunately.

Comment: Any answer which joins on StoredDate  or ORDER BY StoredDate without index will not scale, you have not really a choice to add it..

Comment: You're correct. I'm going to try adding the PK min and max range in BATCH (maybe 100,000 in each block) and see if it speeds things up.

Comment: *"this would need an index on the date and that's something we cannot afford to add unfortunately. "* i wonder why you cant add the index does MSSQL not allow alters and selects/update/deletes to run at the same time.... ?

Comment: I should've been more descriptive. Yes, we can add the additional index, but that'll end up slowing down the inserts on this table and we really want the inserts to be as quick as possible. 

The initial design had additional indexes, but it came at the cost of decreased insert performance, so we took it out.

Comment: *"The initial design had additional indexes, but it came at the cost of decreased insert performance, so we took it out"*  Where those clusterd indexes?  When multiple indexes are in one table using non clusterd indexes is most likely more cheaper for inserts/updates/deletes but on the other side will cause (a bit) more i/o on selects as the indexes are not clusterd annymore

Comment: Are your ID values consecutive? Would it be possible to assume that you could obtain the first ID for day 2 by adding 1 to the last ID for day 1?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the complete records, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, storeddate) order by storeddate asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, storeddate) order by storeddate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1;
```

If you just want the primary key and it is incremented, you can use aggregation:

```
select convert(date, storeddate) as thedate,
       min(pk), max(pk)
from t
group by convert(date, storeddate) ;
```

Comment: Thank you. This just might work. The only challenge I see is that it'll be a really slow query but I'll try to run it in batches with a range min and max range of PK and see if that speeds up the lookup. I'll report back once I'm back infront my my computer.